# asp.net web api 2 url routing attribute not found when hitting it

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using asp.net MVC 5 with Web API 2. I am testing out the new attribute routing, which seems simple enough. I followed the msdn introductory link but still can't get something pretty simple set up.

In the API config file:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In an api controller:

```
public class RecruitingController : ApiController
{
    ...snip...
    [Route("Recruiting/countries/all/")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<Country>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCountries()
    {
        var countries = ctx.Countries.ToList();
        if (countries.Count == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(countries);
    }

}
```

In my view I am calling the routing via ajax. In the chrome developer tools it is trying to hit this route:

```
http://localhost:43736/api/Recruiting/countries/all/
```

and I am getting a 404 response.

Where am I messing up the syntax here? I have the ajax call like so:

```
$.getJSON(apiBaseUrl + "/countries/all/", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function () {
        var dropdownCountry = new DropdownCountry();
        $.each(this, function (k, v) {
            if (k === "Name") {
                dropdownCountry.name = v;
            }
            if (k === "Key") {
                dropdownCountry.key = v;
            } 
        });
        self.orgCountryDdl.push(dropdownCountry);

    });
    alert(DropdownCountry());
});
```

apiBaseUrl is 'api/recruiting'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the conventional route in your request url...your request url should like `http://localhost:43736/Recruiting/countries/all/`...note that requests matching conventional routes can never reach attributed controller/actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the API base URL attribute at the class level too.

then all the method attributes build off of the one at the class level.